# Deriving answers to specific queries from a text

Tags: nlp, automatic-summarization

**Introduction**

I am looking to extract out sentence(s) from a news article for questions like 'who', 'when', 'what', 'why' and 'how'. Now I did some research and found *bert model* which can be utilised to make query based summarizer. But it was not satisfactory as it sentences extracted were small and wrong by huge margins. It makes sense as it was designed to answer full questions and not something like just 'when'.

**Spacy**

I knew about spacy and from that I was able to guess answers for 'who' and 'when'. Also 'what' isn't difficult as it can be obtained from description or first few sentences.

**Problem**

Now I have no idea for 'why' and 'how'. Only thing I can think of is finding words that are used to describe when we give reason to something (why) and  words that describe a  process(how). But again many things become subjective here as it depends on the writer. What is best way possible right now for achieving this, or anything closest to it?

**Examples**

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ejHc3sFZNYKPnmQZhX34R0lY93NAj6Vh/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you give an example of what your model should do? It's still a bit unclear to me. Maybe an example of an input and desired output?

Comment: @ValentinCalomme Added link to some examples.

Comment: Thanks for the examples! If I understand correctly, you want to categorize sections of a document based on which "question" they answer the most? Do you plan to do that in a supervised way (with labelled data) or unsupervised?

Comment: @ValentinCalomme I am looking to do it in an unsupervised way if possible. But if it isn't would definitely love to see the next options.